# wordpress custom registration

Tags: user-registration, wp-signup

is it possible to register user, that his username would be email ?

I tried plugin wp-email-login, but it only logs in with email. Where is no registration with email as username...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

In the admin dashboard, you are able to add a new user with the email address as the user name (thus requiring them to sign in using their email address).

Furthermore, when users register for an account (if you have this feature enabled in your site), they can provide their email address as their username.  They would still need to separately provide their email address, but the two fields (username and email) could be the same value.

Comment: They can't provide username as email because it checks only a-z0-9 characters...